# Boto3 accessing Objects

Tags: python-3.x, boto3, aws-cli

I am new to boto3 and trying to access some items that are in an object:

```
acl = ec2_client.describe_network_acls( Filters=[{'Name':'tag:demo','Values': ['true']}] )
```

This returns the correctly tagged ACL from AWS and stores the object in "acl". Now I would like to get some items out of the object. I need to be able to find the inbound and outbound rules numbered 100 and 105 from the data set below:

```
{
u 'NetworkAcls': [{
    u 'Associations': [],
    u 'NetworkAclId': 'acl-xxxxxxxx',
    u 'VpcId': 'vpc-xxxxxxx',
    u 'Tags': [{
        u 'Value': 'test-demo-dev',
        u 'Key': 'Name'
    }, {
        u 'Value': 'dev',
        u 'Key': 'env'
    }, {
        u 'Value': 'true',
        u 'Key': 'demo'
    }],
    u 'Entries': [{
        u 'RuleNumber': 100,
        u 'Protocol': '6',
        u 'PortRange': {
            u 'To': 443,
            u 'From': 443
        },
        u 'Egress': True,
        u 'RuleAction': 'allow',
        u 'CidrBlock': '34.x.x.x/32'
    }, {
        u 'RuleNumber': 105,
        u 'Protocol': '6',
        u 'PortRange': {
            u 'To': 443,
            u 'From': 443
        },
        u 'Egress': True,
        u 'RuleAction': 'allow',
        u 'CidrBlock': '54.x.x.x/32'
    }, {
        u 'RuleNumber': 110,
        u 'Protocol': '6',
        u 'PortRange': {
            u 'To': 65535,
            u 'From': 1024
        },
        u 'Egress': True,
        u 'RuleAction': 'allow',
        u 'CidrBlock': '10.x.x.x/x'
    }, {
        u 'RuleNumber': 115,
        u 'Protocol': '6',
        u 'PortRange': {
            u 'To': 65535,
            u 'From': 1024
        },
        u 'Egress': True,
        u 'RuleAction': 'allow',
        u 'CidrBlock': '10.x.x.x/x'
    }, {
        u 'RuleNumber': 120,
        u 'Protocol': '6',
        u 'PortRange': {
            u 'To': 65535,
            u 'From': 1024
        },
        u 'Egress': True,
        u 'RuleAction': 'allow',
        u 'CidrBlock': '10.x.x.x/x'
    }, {
        u 'RuleNumber': 32767,
        u 'Protocol': '-1',
        u 'Egress': True,
        u 'CidrBlock': '0.0.0.0/0',
        u 'RuleAction': 'deny'
    }, {
        u 'RuleNumber': 100,
        u 'Protocol': '6',
        u 'PortRange': {
            u 'To': 65535,
            u 'From': 1024
        },
        u 'Egress': False,
        u 'RuleAction': 'allow',
        u 'CidrBlock': '34.x.x.x/32'
    }, {
        u 'RuleNumber': 105,
        u 'Protocol': '6',
        u 'PortRange': {
            u 'To': 65535,
            u 'From': 1024
        },
        u 'Egress': False,
        u 'RuleAction': 'allow',
        u 'CidrBlock': '54.x.x.x/32'
    }, {
        u 'RuleNumber': 110,
        u 'Protocol': '6',
        u 'PortRange': {
            u 'To': 443,
            u 'From': 443
        },
        u 'Egress': False,
        u 'RuleAction': 'allow',
        u 'CidrBlock': '10.x.x.x/x'
    }, {
        u 'RuleNumber': 115,
        u 'Protocol': '6',
        u 'PortRange': {
            u 'To': 443,
            u 'From': 443
        },
        u 'Egress': False,
        u 'RuleAction': 'allow',
        u 'CidrBlock': '10.x.x.x/x'
    }, {
        u 'RuleNumber': 120,
        u 'Protocol': '6',
        u 'PortRange': {
            u 'To': 443,
            u 'From': 443
        },
        u 'Egress': False,
        u 'RuleAction': 'allow',
        u 'CidrBlock': '10.x.x.x/x'
    }, {
        u 'RuleNumber': 32767,
        u 'Protocol': '-1',
        u 'Egress': False,
        u 'CidrBlock': '0.0.0.0/0',
        u 'RuleAction': 'deny'
    }],
    u 'IsDefault': False
}], 'ResponseMetadata': {
    'RetryAttempts': 0,
    'HTTPStatusCode': 200,
    'RequestId': '37258db0-6b9e-4a20-96f3-dc3bc5214b52',
    'HTTPHeaders': {
        'transfer-encoding': 'chunked',
        'vary': 'Accept-Encoding',
        'server': 'AmazonEC2',
        'content-type': 'text/xml;charset=UTF-8',
        'date': 'Tue, 20 Jun 2017 11:22:47 GMT'
    }
}
```

}

In particular I would like to be able to find out the 'CidrBlock' value for inbound and outbound rules 100 and 105.

Can anyone help? I am sure once I see it working for the first time I can go on and apply to other scenarios but just can't seem to get my head around it for the first time.

I guess I need to loop over parts of the object (Entries) and if 'RuleNumber' 100 or 105 and i need to store ingress and egress separately but where to start.....

Comment: This doesn't work but why? for entries in acl['NetworkAcls.Entries']: print(entries)

Comment: is it 100 and 105 or between 100 to 105 (both included) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data you have mentioned contains a unicode string keys and you have accidently added an extra space while asking question .

For e.g -

```
 InCorrect - u 'NetworkAcls'
 Correct - u'NetworkAcls'
```

For getting CIDR Block of rules 100 and 105 from the data you mentioned above, you can get it like this -

```
   NetworkAcls = acl['NetworkAcls']
   for netacl in NetworkAcls:
      entries = netacl['Entries']
      for entry in entries:
         if entry.get('RuleNumber') == 100 or entry.get('RuleNumber') == 105 :
            print(entry.get('CidrBlock' ,None))
```

Output

```
 34.x.x.x/32
 54.x.x.x/32
 34.x.x.x/32
 54.x.x.x/32
```

Is that what you are looking for ?

Comment: that is exactly what I was looking for! The data format is a bit off as I planted it into a json formatter to make it a bit more readable. As I was trying out your code I noticed that the actually format of the acl object output doesn't match the raw output I was getting. I think this is what I have been having so much trouble.

Comment: The acl object seems to contain this - {'NetworkAcls': [], 'ResponseMetadata': {'RequestId': 'e891702b-6d0a-4497-ba4e-57bf440da56a', 'HTTPStatusCode': 200, 'HTTPHeaders': {'content-type': 'text/xml;charset=UTF-8', 'transfer-encoding': 'chunked', 'vary': 'Accept-Encoding', 'date': 'Thu, 22 Jun 2017 11:55:56 GMT', 'server': 'AmazonEC2'}, 'RetryAttempts': 0}}

Comment: Got it - Error in the boto3 session definition so it wasn't picking up the correct account.